# How to delete a pattern in a file that have the same structure but different content?

Tags: sed, replace

I working with a file (.gff3) in which this pattern appears (where # correspond to numbers):

`TRINITY_DN###_c0_g1~~`

example:

```
BAN_TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1_i1        transdecoder    gene    1       580     .       +       .       ID=TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1~~TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1_i1.p1;Name=ORF%20type%3A5prime_partial%20len%3A190%20%28%2B%29%2Cscore%3D182.16
BAN_TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1_i1        transdecoder    mRNA    1       580     .       +       .       ID=TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1_i1.p1;Parent=TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1~~TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1_i1.p1;Name=ORF%20type%3A5prime_partial%20len%3A190%20%28%2B%29%2Cscore%3D182.16
BAN_TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1_i1        transdecoder    exon    1       580     .       +       .       ID=TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1_i1.p1.exon1;Parent=TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1_i1.p1
BAN_TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1_i1        transdecoder    CDS     1       570     .       +       0       ID=cds.TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1_i1.p1;Parent=TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1_i1.p1
BAN_TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1_i1        transdecoder    three_prime_UTR 571     580     .       +       .       ID=TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1_i1.p1.utr3p1;Parent=TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1_i1.p1

BAN_TRINITY_DN101_c0_g1_i1      transdecoder    gene    1       230     .       -       .       ID=TRINITY_DN101_c0_g1~~TRINITY_DN101_c0_g1_i1.p1;Name=ORF%20type%3Ainternal%20len%3A77%20%28-%29%2Cscore%3D24.09
BAN_TRINITY_DN101_c0_g1_i1      transdecoder    mRNA    1       230     .       -       .       ID=TRINITY_DN101_c0_g1_i1.p1;Parent=TRINITY_DN101_c0_g1~~TRINITY_DN101_c0_g1_i1.p1;Name=ORF%20type%3Ainternal%20len%3A77%20%28-%29%2Cscore%3D24.09
BAN_TRINITY_DN101_c0_g1_i1      transdecoder    exon    1       230     .       -       .       ID=TRINITY_DN101_c0_g1_i1.p1.exon1;Parent=TRINITY_DN101_c0_g1_i1.p1
BAN_TRINITY_DN101_c0_g1_i1      transdecoder    CDS     3       230     .       -       0       ID=cds.TRINITY_DN101_c0_g1_i1.p1;Parent=TRINITY_DN101_c0_g1_i1.p1
```

I'd like to simply delete the pattern, so the output would be something like this:

```
BAN_TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1_i1        transdecoder    gene    1       580     .       +       .       ID=TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1_i1.p1;Name=ORF%20type%3A5prime_partial%20len%3A190%20%28%2B%29%2Cscore%3D182.16
BAN_TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1_i1        transdecoder    mRNA    1       580     .       +       .       ID=TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1_i1.p1;Parent=TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1_i1.p1;Name=ORF%20type%3A5prime_partial%20len%3A190%20%28%2B%29%2Cscore%3D182.16
BAN_TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1_i1        transdecoder    exon    1       580     .       +       .       ID=TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1_i1.p1.exon1;Parent=TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1_i1.p1
BAN_TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1_i1        transdecoder    CDS     1       570     .       +       0       ID=cds.TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1_i1.p1;Parent=TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1_i1.p1
BAN_TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1_i1        transdecoder    three_prime_UTR 571     580     .       +       .       ID=TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1_i1.p1.utr3p1;Parent=TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1_i1.p1

BAN_TRINITY_DN101_c0_g1_i1      transdecoder    gene    1       230     .       -       .       ID=TRINITY_DN101_c0_g1_i1.p1;Name=ORF%20type%3Ainternal%20len%3A77%20%28-%29%2Cscore%3D24.09
BAN_TRINITY_DN101_c0_g1_i1      transdecoder    mRNA    1       230     .       -       .       ID=TRINITY_DN101_c0_g1_i1.p1;Parent=TRINITY_DN101_c0_g1_i1.p1;Name=ORF%20type%3Ainternal%20len%3A77%20%28-%29%2Cscore%3D24.09
BAN_TRINITY_DN101_c0_g1_i1      transdecoder    exon    1       230     .       -       .       ID=TRINITY_DN101_c0_g1_i1.p1.exon1;Parent=TRINITY_DN101_c0_g1_i1.p1
BAN_TRINITY_DN101_c0_g1_i1      transdecoder    CDS     3       230     .       -       0       ID=cds.TRINITY_DN101_c0_g1_i1.p1;Parent=TRINITY_DN101_c0_g1_i1.p1
```

I tried to use `sed` to do it, however, since the pattern change in terms of size and composition and I don't know how to perform the character deletion by taking this into account (I'm quite new on using bash).

Does anyone has an idea of how to do???

Comment: What is the `sed` command you used?

Comment: @PierreFrançois I tried thing like this ```sed 's/TRINITY.*~~//'``` But it did not work I think maybe because there are many "TRINITY" on the line

Comment: What do you mean with "it did not work"? Do you mean it deleted a too big part of the line? I guess it didn't delete anything, because the `*` operator of the regex is greedy, and it consumes by itself the remaining part of the line, and then `~~` can't match anything more. Try my solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
sed 's/TRINITY_DN[0-9]*_c0_g1~~//' input.gff3
```

`[0-9]*` matches any number of consecutive digits.

Answer (score 1):

If you agree to write the pattern you want to delete according to the syntax of the regex, just issue:

```sh
PATTERN='TRINITY_DN[0-9][0-9][0-9]_c0_g1~~'
sed "/$PATTERN/s///g" file.gff3
```

I supposed the pattern could occur several times on one line. If this is not the case, remove the `g` at the end of the first argument of the `sed` command.

If you don't know how many digits you will have behind `TRINITY_DN`, you can replace `[0-9][0-9][0-9]` by `[0-9]*`.

If you want another syntax for describing your patterns (v.gr. `#` instead of `[0-9]`), please specify.